# Obtain referential integrity at the expense of 2NF- is it a reasonable trade off?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

Consider the following two tables:

```
Table A: [K1, K2, PropA] 

Table B: [K3, PropB]
```

The primary key of Table A is composite `[K1,K2]`.
The primary key of table B is `K3`.

Table has an inclusive dependency on on table B- values in `K3` have to be matched by value in K2. Unfortunately, since `K2` is not a unique primary key, I can't define an foreign key constraint on these columns.

as I see it the solution is to either enforce it in the application layer or to propagate the `K1` column to table B, so that it will contain the entire foreign key of table A.

**My question**: is this considered a good or bad practice in DB design? Assume that adding the extra column is not a problem from a maintenance perspective or integrity perspective (insert is transactional).

I am using MSSQL and Oracle.

Comment: Is `K3` unique? Can you put the foreign key on `Table A -> K2` to map to `K3`? We need to know more specifics about the relation of the data to help you, but what you describe (or how I understand it) does not sound like good practice.

Comment: @Vitaliy You didn't mention what DBMS you are using. Note that not all DBMSs suffer this limitation. In some cases (MySQL is one example) you can create referential integrity constraints between two tables even where the target of such a constraint is non-unique and not nullable. There are possible workarounds for software that doesn't directly support such constraints. Your question does raise an important point: the often poor support for data integrity constraints offered in modern database software means database designers sometimes have to make some awkward compromises.

Comment: If there are multiple values of `K1` for a particular `K2` value, which one would be used in Table B?

Comment: @sqlvogel - MSSQL and Oracle.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - K2 which is unique in B.

Comment: @Vitaliy - I'm not sure I understand your response. You were talking about including `K1` in table B as one possible option. Which `K1` value would you be taking from Table A if there are *multiple* rows in Table A with a single `K2` value?

Comment: @Damien, in that case I think the underlying assumption is that any and all combinations of k1/k2 might be populated in B. Hence the violation of 2NF: key (k3,k1) where k3->PropB. The better alternative is not to do that and to enforce the constraint in other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Create table C, with just one attribute, K2, which is the primary key. Now you can reference K2 with a foreign key constraint.

It would probably be a bad idea to put the K1 attribute into table B. If I've understood you correctly doing that looks like it would create a non-key dependency in violation of 2NF.

Your question does raise an important point: the often poor support for data integrity constraints offered in modern database software means database designers sometimes have to make some awkward compromises.

Comment: But the problem remains, since I still need to maintain referential integrity between A and C. The violation is indeed there. The question is whether the gain is greater than the loss (I think so, but I am looking for an expert advice).

Comment: You can create a foreign key constraint in A which references C and another in B which references C. Integrity is maintained in 2 RI constraints instead of 1.

Comment: I see, but than I can't use cascading delete.. (That starts from table A and should propagate to B). I did not mention this initially, but it is a shame to lose this.

Comment: @sqlvogel: B might reference a value that is in C, but is not in A.

Comment: @Mike: "Your question does raise an important point: the often poor support for data integrity constraints offered in modern database software means database designers sometimes have to make some awkward compromises."

Answer (score 1):

"... the solution is to either enforce it in the application layer or to propagate ..."

You see right or you see wrong, depending on perspective.

The true solution is for the DBMS vendors to support the general case of inclusion dependencies, of which the foreign key is only a special case.

But as long as the DBMS vendors don't do that, you are right, as long as you keep restraining yourself to those vendors' offerings, you'll have no other choice than to move constraint enforcement to the application [*], or screw up the design with all those ugly hacks you need in order to get your constraint enforced using just FKs.

A system that offers you a solution that involves neither of "enforcement in the application" and "screw up the design" is at shark.armchair.mb.ca/~erwin.  Disclosure : that project is of my own making.

[*] or put all the constraint enforcement code in triggers, such that at least a new application cannot "forget" to enforce some given existing business rule.